# primefaces p:rowEdit cascading selectoneMenu

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, cdi

I have an Office datatable that displays department name and role name. department and role are objects. when I select rowedit, when there is a change in the department, the roles should be reloaded. I am not sure how to pass the selected department and rerender the roles.

```
<p:column headerText="Department">     
   <p:cellEditor>  
       <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{office.department.name}" /></f:facet>  
       <f:facet name="input">
         <p:selectOneMenu value="#{office.department}" converter="#{departmentConverter}" style="width:96%" >   
           <f:selectItems value="#{departments}" var="dept" itemLabel="#{dept.name}" itemValue="#{dept}"/>  
           <p:ajax event="change"  listener="#{officeManagmentController.onDepartmentChanged()}"/>
         </p:selectOneMenu>
       </f:facet>
   </p:cellEditor> 
</p:column>  

<p:column headerText="Role">     
   <p:cellEditor>  
       <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{office.role.name}" /></f:facet>  
       <f:facet name="input">
         <p:selectOneMenu value="#{office.role}" converter="#{roleConverter}" style="width:96%" >   
           <f:selectItems value="#{officeManagementController.assignableRoles}" var="role" itemLabel="#{role.name}" itemValue="#{role}"/>  
         </p:selectOneMenu>
       </f:facet>
   </p:cellEditor> 
</p:column>
```

the following is my officecontroller managedbean

```
@ConversationScoped

public class OfficeManagementController implements Serializable {

    public void onRowSelect(SelectEvent event) {  
        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(selectedOffice.getName()+" selected"); 
        selectedDepartment=selectedOffice.getDepartment();
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);  
    }  


    public void onDepartmentChanged() {

        if(selectedOffice!=null)selectedSystem=selectedOffice.getDepartment();
        log.info("Calling onDepartmentChanged " + ((selectedDepartment != null) ? selectedDepartment.getName() : "null"));
        if(selectedDepartment != null) {
            assignableRoles = roleRepo.findByDepartment(selectedDepartment);
            for(int i=0;i<assignableRoles.size();i++){
                System.out.println(assignableRoles.get(i));
            }

        } else {
            assignableRoles=null;
        }
    }
}
```

What I noticed is the selectedOffice is null in the onDepartmentChanged() method, but in the onrowselect, the value is not null.  I haven't progressed more than that. I have to dynamically change the roles when a department changes. Why is the selectedOffice null?

Comment: It might help readers if you could show a minimal amount of code that demonstrated the problem.

Comment: Where are you selecting the office? You are not showing that in this code, only departments and roles from the office. Just control the `selectedOffice` setter and see when it is being written with `null`.

Comment: selectedOffice is the rowselection of the datatable